# Sort using only some columns

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a 600MB tab delimited file that needs to be sorted using only the first two columns. Any lines already in order by those columns should remain in the existing order. My efforts using `sort` and `--key` seem to keep sorting the lines by the other columns.

This is an example of the unsorted file:

```
1244072768  7234    Z
1244072768  7234    e
1244072768  7234    b
1244072768  7234    r
1244072768  7234    a
1244072768  7341    C
1244072768  7341    a
1244072768  7234    -
1244072768  7341    r
1244072768  7341    t
1244072768  7341    -
1244072769  4237    W
1244072769  4237    a
1244072769  4237    s
1244072769  4237    h
1244072769  4237    -
```

The result should be something like:

```
1244072768  7234    Z
1244072768  7234    e
1244072768  7234    b
1244072768  7234    r
1244072768  7234    a
1244072768  7234    -
1244072768  7341    C
1244072768  7341    a
1244072768  7341    r
1244072768  7341    t
1244072768  7341    -
1244072769  4237    W
1244072769  4237    a
1244072769  4237    s
1244072769  4237    h
1244072769  4237    -
```

I have tried `sort -k 1n -k 2n test.log;`, `sort -k 1 -k 2 test.log;` and `sort -k 1,2 test.log;` and all of them sort by the entire line. Is there any way to use standard linux/unix command line tools to sort this file by only the first two columns?

Comment: To explain why the file is in this convoluted pattern, I have several processes all writing multi line messages to the file. Because of this sometimes two processes overlap and mix their messages. The first column is a Unix time-stamp, and the second is the process ID. I need all of the messages written by the same process in the same second grouped together, and the final '-' line to be always last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `-s` to get a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

```
sort -k 1,2 -s test.log
```

From the man page:

```
-s, --stable
       stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, the examples I found never included that flag